# Undefined offset: 0 with LARAVEL 5.6 and GuzzleHttp POST request

Tags: guzzle, laravel-5.6, uber-api

can you help me please, I want to use UBER API with GuzzleHttp

```
    $uber_client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/',
        'timeout'  => 2.0,
        'headers' => [
            'content_type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language' => 'fr_FR',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer $uber_access_token"],
    ]);
```

to have Ride Request - Estimate :

```
        $resp_uber = $uber_client->post("requests/estimate", [
        'auth' => [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer $uber_access_token"
            ],
        'form_params' =>   [
            'start_latitude' => $start_latitude,
            'start_longitude' => $start_longitude,
            'end_latitude' => $end_latitude,
            'end_longitude' => $end_longitude,
            ]
    ]);
```

=> Erreur :

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   Undefined offset: 0

Comment: I think your `'Authorization' => "Bearer $uber_access_token"` should be in the headers.

Comment: already tried in Headers , it did not change anything